# Trouble using Mujoco key in virtual env

Tags: python, terminal, deep-learning

has anyone ever had a problem using the mujoco key in a virtual env? I am running the cmds from this git : https://github.com/HumanCompatibleAI/adversarial-policies and when I try to train the adversary I get the error : Found your MuJoCo binaries but not license key. Please put your key into ~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt or set MUJOCO_PY_MJKEY_PATH. My mujoco key is located ~/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin/mjkey.txt currently (I have also tried placing it just in ~/.mujoco). Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Get your licens [here](https://www.roboti.us/license.html). You will recieve a mjKey.txt file. Save that file under  C:%Userpath%/.mujoco